# set default scaling windows 10 all users all monitors

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, regedit, scaling

how do i default the scaling on all monitors on a device for all users?

we have a station in each Operating Room. a computer with one normal sized monitor and two flatscreen tvs. In order to get a radiology program to work correctly and show the xrays properly the monitors all need to be set to a scaling of 100%. it seems that the two flatscreens are being detected by windows and windows is setting them to 150%.

i've tried LogPixels set to decimal value of 96 in regedit @ Control Panel\Desktop. but no success yet with it

GPOs are not really an option as every group that uses these 4 computers have users that also use other devices with their own scaling requirements.

Comment: The last sentence makes your question unclear. If you want to set scaling to 100%, then please inform us of the criteria that sets apart the computers that do not need to be locked to a specific scaling. GPO can be applied to specific AD Groups. So if you want the OR computers set to 100%, then just create a group to contain them.

Comment: Right now the 4 are in the group Surgery, along with all the computers in surgery department.  Some of those computers are personal machines that people use at larger scaling, specialist machines for scopes, radiology viewing pcs, etc.  i guess we could create a new AD group just for these 4 machines.  I'll talk with my sysadmin and see about creating a new group.  thanks for the feedback!!

Comment: Did some research on this, and apparently Scaling policy is set in the registry at the User level, not the machine level. It is still possible to apply it to all users on a specific computer, but it will require some finagling.